# Find T(x) linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1\\
    1 & -1 & 1\\
    2 & 1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Find $T(x)$ if

$$x =\begin{bmatrix}
    2\\
    1\\
    -4
  \end{bmatrix}$$

**What I did:**

$T(x)$ = $Ax $ = $b$

So, I performed matrix multiplication $A \cdot b$ and got an answer

$$T(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    -3\\
    1
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Can someone please verify this answer? I do not think this is the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: The answer is correct. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: I think it is incorrect because A*b =/= b*A here (I know matrix multiplication is not commutative, but this would imply that there is more than one value of x.)

Comment: You are asked to find $b$ such that $T(x)=b$. Since $T(x)=Ax,$ the problem is to compute $Ax$ given $A$ and $x$. Here doesn't matter $xA,$ in fact, $xA$ is not defined in this case.

Comment: @stackofhay42 What do you mean by $bA$?  This is not defined.

Comment: Oh I used an online calculator and it gave me an answer for $xA$. I guess this is correct then. Thanks!

@littleO yes sorry I meant xA

Comment: @stackofhay42 $xA$ isn't defined either...you multiplication is correct, though. What is actually bothering you?